# Express 4 Route Issues

Tags: node.js, express

Just learning nodejs, express, jade. While making progress, I am having trouble understanding how the routes work.  I have the routes in a routes folder and the views (Jade files) in a views folder.  And that works, but I don't see how.

Let's say I have a page foo.  In routes, I have foo.js:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    /* GET foo page*/
    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('foo', {title: 'Foo' });
    });
    module.exports = router;
```

The menu link in the Jade file that calls Foo has an href="/foo" attribute.  How come router.get('/', ... ) works?  Shouldn't it have to be

```
    router.get('/foo', function(req, res) {
        res.render('foo', {title: 'Foo' });
    });
```

When I try to do that, however, it can't find the route and I get a 404, which seems counter to the router docs.  I could just go with it and have all the routes get('/', ...) or post('/', ...), which does work, but it just seems wrong.

What am I missing?

Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 2):

Your `app.js` file probably contains a line that looks like the following:

```
app.use('/foo', require('./routes/foo'));
```

This means that any route defined in `./routes/foo` will be relative to `/foo`.  Therefore, your `/` route is accessed via `/foo/`.

Comment: Actually, there is a line:

Comment: Sorry... I didn't know about the 5 minute limit. The site should tell you up from about that when you go to edit.

Actually, there is a line in app.js: 
    
    var foo = require('./routes/foo');

followed some lines later by

    app.use('/foo', foo);

which I guess amounts to the same thing as your answer. 

I am still a bit confused on the use case for app.use() and the router.get() argument differences, but you have solved my practical issue. Thanks!

Comment: `app.use()`/`router.use()` are HTTP method-agnostic and can be used to insert generic middleware or to mount routers.